# Is a probability measure on a product space a product measure?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Xi^{N},\mathcal{E}^{N})$ product space of the measurable space $(\Xi,\mathcal{E})$ where $N>0$. Let $\lambda$ be a probability measure on $(\Xi^{N},\mathcal{E}^{N})$.

**The question:** Is $\lambda$ be a product measure?, that is, are there $\mu_{i}$, $i=1,\ldots,N$, probability measures on $(\Xi,\mathcal{E})$ such that $\lambda=\otimes_{i=1}^{N}\mu_{i}$?

Another way of looking at my question is considering $\mathcal{M(\Xi)}$ the set of all probability measures supported on $\Xi$ and $\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$ the set of all probability measures supported on $\Xi^{N}$, ***Can we identify $\mathcal{M}(\Xi^{N})$=$\mathcal{M}(\Xi)^{N}$?***

***If the answer is no, under what conditions is this identification possible?***

Comment: If you have two "nice" spaces $X$ and $Y$, then the Banach space of finite signed measures $\mathcal M(X \times Y)$ can be canonically identified with the tensor product $\mathcal M(X) \otimes \mathcal M(Y)$, with a suitable cross-norm. So, every measure can be decomposed into an infinite linear combination of product measures. This identification also explains the suggestive notation $\mu \otimes \nu$ for product-measures.

Comment: @Shalop What does "nice" mean in this context? Where can I find a reference that reaffirms your answer?

Answer (score 2):

No. The simplest counterexample is $\Xi = \{0,1\}$, with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra, and $N=2$.

Let $\lambda\{(0,0)\}=1-p$, $\lambda\{(1,1)\}=p$, and $\lambda\{(0,1)\}=\lambda\{(1,0)\}=0$.
This is a probability measure on $(\Xi^N, \mathcal{E}^N)$, but is not a product measure.

---

In the language of random variables, this can be summarized as "for a joint distribution on $(X,Y)$, it is not necessarily true that $X$ and $Y$ are independent."

Answer (score 2):

Product measures correspond to independence. Specifically, if $\lambda$ is a measure on $\Xi^N$, let $X=(X_1,\ldots,X_N)$ be a $\Xi^N$-valued random variable with law $\lambda$. Then $\lambda$ is a product measure if and only if $X_1,\ldots,X_N$ are independent random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Some measures on a product space are product measures, but most are not.

This question is similar to asking if all matrices have rank one.